# An adjective that would subtly imply that the criticism is not a personal grudge

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, adjectives

I have expressed disapproval of sb/sth and my professor has escalated the issue to the management stating behavioral issues. 
I am writing a letter explaining what went wrong.

**I want to state that the criticism was not harsh, not intended to malign sb**.

What are the options, please ?

Comment: What lead to your disapproval of sb/sth ?  You can use "review" instead of criticism and yet sound better.

Comment: Nothing personal

Comment: If you are criticizing someone there is no way to "prove" that it is not due to a personal grudge.  Any attempts to deny a grudge (beyond the obligatory brief "nothing personal" statement) will only make matters worse.  Your best approach is to be as objective and fair-handed as possible.

Comment: Did you intend to provide *constructive criticism*?

Comment: This question is asking for writing advice and or workplace etiquette advice.

Comment: @Jim, tbh, there's a lot of crossover. His/her actual title (the core of her/his question) is a single-word request, although phrase request would be more appropriate, in my opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest using `specifically` to qualify your criticism.

Given that the administration/management will have heard the professor's side of the story, you may get some credit for admitting it was criticism:

> I **specifically** criticized ______, intending **only** to point out _________, not to in any way demean [your professor].

It's hard to build a case for you without knowing the context, but I would try to use language which makes your argument positive. Some possible examples:

- *I said this because I believed that teaching ______ instead of _______ would **give the class a broader perspective**.*
- *I hoped simply to suggest **an improvement**.*
- *I only wished the professor would consider ______ instead, because of my understanding that _______.*

Another idea is to include concession relating to the quality or value of the class and/or your professor:

> I would like to reiterate that [your professor]'s class has greatly benefited my understanding of ______ and I believe [your professor] does an excellent job of _________.

It might be best to begin with this sort of concession to set the tone.

*Note: I apologize that, yes, `specifically` is an adverb, not an adjective.*

Comment: I think this is an excellent set of advice but sadly isn't what the OP asked for: just one adjective.

Comment: @Avon: specifically `specifically`. You are correct, but I hope it's not inappropriate to throw in other information.

Comment: No it's not inappropriate. I hadn't realised that word was the answer. In that case +1

Comment: @Avon, then I needed to clarify more. Edited and thanks! :)

Comment: The word "specifically" sounds bitter.

Comment: @HotLicks I'll confess I can see that with `specifically` by itself, but I think in the context of a real sentence it works.

Comment: In the sentence you gave as an example it sounds bitter.

Comment: ***Disinterested*** is a possibility, but has problems. http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disinterested
   
 ": not influenced by personal feelings, opinions, or concerns
: having no desire to know about a particular thing : not interested"

The problem, of course, is that many people think "Disinterested" means "uninterested"; to my surprise, uninterested is even a second definition.

Answer (score 5):

"Not harsh" is a subjective quality. So I would try to frame "harshness of criticism" as a quality that is defined by a third party, rather than a quality that is defined by you (Party A) or them (Party B).

> I tried to give [Party A] an *appropriately delicate, well-intentioned* critique.

You could then expound on that:

> This critique was not *ad hominem*, and it is quite unfortunate
>   that it was understood as such. While I regret the misunderstanding, I
>   stand by my original assessment of the situation as it was motivated
>   by *[a desire to further some academic/aesthetic aim, which is
>   decidedly neither sadistic nor self-serving]*

Comment: You could then expound on this: "This critique was in no way _ad hominem_, and it is quite unfortunate that it was understood as such. While I regret the misunderstanding, I stand by my original assessment of the situation as it was motivated by [a desire to further some academic/aesthetic aim, which is decidedly neither sadistic nor self-serving]"

Comment: You should really edit and add that to your answer!

Answer (score 0):

If the subject of your criticism was merely another’s work product, then you could (possibly) claim that your critique was *an objective and fair appraisal, intended* [*constructively*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/constructive) and certainly *not* meant to be [*slanderous*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/slander) or [*defamatory*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/defamatory).

If, however, your criticism also included reference to the author of the work product, then you might add that it was offered *without malice aforethought*.

> [**malice aforethought**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/malice%20aforethought) *noun*: deliberate malice: premeditated malice; specifically:  malice in fact or implied malice in the intention of one who has had sufficient time to act with premeditation in the doing of something unlawful.

(links & definitions courtesy of Merriam-Webster *online*)

Comment: I think the word that most closely satisfies the question is "objective", which is mentioned in this answer but not highlighted, though many other possible candidates are.  Unfortunately, though, I don't think that "objective" would do the questioner much good anyway, since calling him- or herself objective would be tantamount to saying that the professor is _not_ objective, which will likely only exacerbate the situation.

Comment: @Doug Warren - your point is fair, perhaps 'objective' should be preceded by a qualifier, e.g., *intended* to be ...

Comment: "malice aforethought" is a purely legal term that would not be used outside a legal context and is unfamiliar even to most native speakers.

Answer (score 0):

Unkind or unsupportive.

I'll add a few thoughts about the awkward situation you find yourself in.

If you didn't mean to start a fight, then it might be good to try to help the offended party calm down and start looking at things more rationally.  -- But without being defensive, aggressive, or conciliatory.

It can help to begin by validating the person's feelings.  For example:

I am very sorry if my comments about So-and-so's approach were perceived as unkind or unsupportive.  Respectful collaboration is important when doing science, and I will try to be more attentive of how my comments might be perceived in future.

You might want to stop there, or you might want to tell the story from your point of view, as a point of information (not as defensiveness).

Answer (score 0):

You want to say:

> that the criticism was not harsh, not intended to malign sb

Since you are in a pickle with the management, it seems that what was **intended** and what was **perceived** are two different things. To clarify your intention, *well-intended* is a great choice (offered by Robert). What went wrong was a misunderstanding which you can't blame on the listeners (because that would probably just escalate matters further), but you can blame it on the circumstances, i.e. *the unfortunate choice of words in a spur of the moment* or shorter:

**[hastily](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/hasty) [phrased](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/phrase?q=phrased#phrase__9)** or **hastily put** criticism

I opted for the two-word [adverb+ past participle] construction that can be used attributively instead of the adjective *hasty* because the second might imply that the essence of criticism was hasty, and I didn't get the impression that you want to actually say that. (Depending on how far you want to go you might even say *clumsily phrased* which still refers just to your choice of words, not the intended meaning of your comment.)

---

An aside: Not what you asked for, but since you have the word-choice tag, maybe the word "criticism" isn't the best choice to alleviate the situation. Milder words would include: remark > suggestion > comment.